# Regex in RewriteRule, passing to bootstrap PHP file

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out a solution for passing all relevant HTTP requests to my index.php bootstrap file.

The two rules I want to enforce are:

- Any directory,
- Any file with a `.html` or `.ajax` file extension (in any directory).

None of these files or directories actually exist - bootstrap PHP file will dynamically output relevant content.

---

Here is my current .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}$1 !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+(?:\.html?)?)$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule \.ajax$ index.php [L]
```

The RewriteCond has been commented out as it didn't seem to have any effect, and with the correct RewriteRule it will be made obsolete anyway (image files, javascript files, etc. will not be matched by the rule so don't need to be checked for existance).

I think a regex expert could easily solve this, a plus would also be to combine the two rules into one regex.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule should do it:

```
RewriteRule .+\.(html|ajax)$ index.php
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for `home.html` and `main/page.html` but ignores directories i.e. `main` and `main/admin`.

Comment: @Greg: Well, that URL path doesn’t have a file name extension.

Comment: I wanted the RewriteRule to match directories too, is that possible?

Comment: @Greg: Then what is a directory?

Comment: Hmm, I guess anything that doesn't have an extension, but also can have multiple forward slashes in

Comment: @Greg: Then try this pattern: `^([^/.]+/)*[^/.]+(\.(html|ajax))?$`. But what else is there besides files and directories?

Comment: Files that aren't .html or .ajax - they shouldn't be matched by the regex. So the regex should only match .html and .ajax files and directories. All other files should be left untouched.